# How Do I assert different pages in phpunit without the use of selenium .

Tags: php, phpunit

I have to test a website form code in phpunit. how can i request the controller to open the url for me without using the selenium or any web driver.  the commands like open() ; url(); are not working in this case. so please guide me for the same. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write phpunit tests with cUrl extension, load html content and do asserts, but it is not proper way. 
What's wrong with Selenium and Web Drivers? 
You can try some different approaches like [Codeseption](http://codeception.com/11-12-2013/working-with-phpunit-and-selenium-webdriver.html).